# Steps to make a loadable DLL of some tcl methods in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tcl

I want to create a loadable DLL of some of my tcl methods. But I am not getting how to do this. For that I have taken a simple example of tcl api which adds two numbers and prints the sum. Now I want to create a loadable DLL for this to export this tcl functionality.

But I am not understanding how to do it in Visual Studio. I have written a C code which can call this tcl api and get the sum of two integers, but again I don't want it to do this way. I want to create a DLL file to use this tcl functionality. How can I create this DLL on Visual Studio 2010.

Below is my sample tcl program that I am using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh8.5
proc add_two_nos { } {

set a 10

set b 20

set c [expr { $a + $b } ]

puts " c is $c ......."

}
```

And here is the C code which can use this tcl functionality :

```
#include <tcl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Tcl_Interp *interp;
    int code;
    char *result;

    Tcl_FindExecutable(argv[0]);
    interp = Tcl_CreateInterp();
    code = Tcl_Eval(interp, "source myscript.tcl; add_two_nos");

    /* Retrieve the result... */
    result = Tcl_GetString(Tcl_GetObjResult(interp));

    /* Check for error! If an error, message is result. */
    if (code == TCL_ERROR) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR in script: %s\n", result);
    exit(1);
    }

    /* Print (normal) result if non-empty; we'll skip handling encodings for now */
    if (strlen(result)) {
    printf("%s\n", result);
    }

    /* Clean up */
    Tcl_DeleteInterp(interp);
    exit(0);
    }
```

I have successfully compiled this code with the below command
gcc simple_addition_wrapper_new.c -I/usr/include/tcl8.5/ -ltcl8.5 -o simple_addition_op

The above code is working with the expected output.

What steps do I need to take to create a loadable dll for this in Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the answers to this question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929478/how-to-make-a-loadable-dll-to-use-tcl-code-functionality-by-any-program/13935698#13935698) it gives the basic outline of the process you need to go through.  There are links from my answer to some Microsoft MSDN articles on creating DLLs.

To go into this in a little more detail for a C++ dll that has Tcl embedded in it.

The first step is to create a new visual studio project with the correct type, one that is going to build a dll that exports symbols. My example project is called TclEmbeddedInDll and that name appears in code in symbols such as TCLEMBEDDEDINDLL_API that are generated by Visual Studio.

The dllmain.cpp look like this:

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "stdafx.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
    )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        {
            allocInterp() ;
            break ;
        }

    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        break ;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        break ;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        {
            destroyInterp() ;
            break;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

The `allocInterp()` and `destroyInterp()` functions are defined in the TclEmbeddedInDll.h, the reason for using functions here rather than creating the Tcl_Interp directly is that it keeps the details about Tcl away from the DLL interface.  If you create the interp here then you have to include tcl.h and then things get complicated when you try and use the DLL in another program.

The TclEmbeddedInDll.h and .cpp are shown next, the function `fnTclEmbeddedInDll()` is the one that is exported from the DLL - I'm using C linkage for this rather than C++ as it makes it easier to call the function from other languages IMHO.

```
// The following ifdef block is the standard way of creating macros which make exporting 
// from a DLL simpler. All files within this DLL are compiled with the TCLEMBEDDEDINDLL_EXPORTS
// symbol defined on the command line. This symbol should not be defined on any project
// that uses this DLL. This way any other project whose source files include this file see 
// TCLEMBEDDEDINDLL_API functions as being imported from a DLL, whereas this DLL sees symbols
// defined with this macro as being exported.
#ifdef TCLEMBEDDEDINDLL_EXPORTS
#define TCLEMBEDDEDINDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define TCLEMBEDDEDINDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" {
    TCLEMBEDDEDINDLL_API void fnTclEmbeddedInDll(void);

}

void allocInterp() ;
void destroyInterp() ;


// TclEmbeddedInDll.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

extern "C" {

    static Tcl_Interp *interp ;

    // This is an example of an exported function.
    TCLEMBEDDEDINDLL_API void fnTclEmbeddedInDll(void)
    {
        int code;
        const char *result;
        code = Tcl_Eval(interp, "source simple_addition.tcl; add_two_nos");
        result = Tcl_GetString(Tcl_GetObjResult(interp));
    }
}

void allocInterp() 
{
    Tcl_FindExecutable(NULL);
    interp = Tcl_CreateInterp();
}

void destroyInterp()
{
    Tcl_DeleteInterp(interp);
}
```

The implementation of allocInterp() and destroyInterp() is very naive, no error checking is done.

Finally for the Dll the stdafx.h file ties it all together like this:

```
// stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files that are used frequently, but
// are changed infrequently
//

#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN             // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
// Windows Header Files:
#include <windows.h>

// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here
#include <tcl.h>
#include "TclEmbeddedInDll.h"
```

Comment: Thanks for this help Jackson. I will definitely try this and come up with my findings. I have gone through the steps to do in visual studio to create dll for this but has some confusion. So for this paricular example if you can give the steps for how to create dll in studio it will be very helpful for me. Thanks in advance . You have done great work.

Comment: Thanks Jackson, i have created the dll using above exact code and method in visual studio. Now i want to check whether will this dll provide the tcl functionality of addition of two numbers correctly or not. Is there any way by that i can check it. I will again very thankful for this  help. Please reply .

Comment: I'm really not sure what your asking for?  What have you tried yourself and how does the result you get differ from what you expect.  If you have some code of your own then post it as a new question and ask a more specific question.